# How do i test create/update/delete Zend_Db_Table_Abstract methods using Phactory in Zend Framework with PHPUnit?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I wanted to use Phactory to test part of the submit action source as given below:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/050a0p2a6

Using Phactory, it is assured that the data is going into DB but the problem is in code coverage as some of the lines are still highlighted in red.

How do i test those lines so that the code coverage will be shown in green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in orange indicates code that the code has run but is not covered by any of your tests. In the screenshot, it looks like your if condition is false, which your test does not cover. The expression in question looks like your data is not valid, perhaps related to your fields not validating.